# Using Console.WriteLine during Console.ReadLine

Tags: c#, mono, console-application

I've got the following code:

```
bool loop = true;
        LongbowWorkerThread Worker = new LongbowWorkerThread();
        Thread w = new Thread(Worker.UpdateChannel);
        w.Start();

        string inText = string.Empty;

        while (loop) {
            inText = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(inText);
        }
```

At this point, the worker thread simply echoes a string every 5000ms. The problem is that the printed string overlaps the user's already-entered text, which isn't ideal and looks quite ugly (although it doesn't affect the actual data returned by Console.ReadLine.)

Is there a way to prevent this overlap?

Comment: "Is there a way to prevent this overlap?" Yes: the simplest one would be to write a little GUI. It shouldn't take long - fter all, it's 2012, not 1982, and you have plenty of UI frameworks inside MONO to choose from. Your users are going to love it, too.

Comment: Not what I asked. I'm writing a quick commandline utility, just for funsies and to teach myself how to munge around in textmode. If you don't think I should do it, that's fine - but if that's the case, find another dude to advise. ;)

Comment: @sudowned "Not what I asked." That's why I didn't answer, just commented.

Comment: What is the use of your LongbowWorkerThread Thread. Using readline and writeline without it no overlap occurs. So Updatechannel  function causes the overlap i think.

Comment: @MdKamruzzamanPallob: Because I need the app to update even without user input.

Comment: I think Updating channel from same thread(which is used by readline and writeline) will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Console.CursorLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorleft.aspx) and [Console.CursorRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop.aspx) properties to note the cursors location, shift it, output your text, then shift it back.

Edit: Here's a sample I just threw together, works well based on the 60 seconds of testing I threw at it.

```
        int fooCursorTop = Console.CursorTop + 1;

        var timer2 = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer2.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(delegate
            {
                int tempCursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                int tempCursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                Console.CursorTop = fooCursorTop;
                Console.WriteLine("Foo");
                Console.CursorLeft = tempCursorLeft;
                Console.CursorTop = tempCursorTop;
                fooCursorTop++;
            });
        timer2.Start();

        string input = string.Empty;
        while (input != "quit")
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.CursorTop = fooCursorTop;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            fooCursorTop += 2;
        }
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. While it can in some cases be used to prevent overwriting the `ReadLine` contents, those contents **do not follow the cursor** - they merely get abandoned elsewhere on the screen instead of being overwritten.

Comment: @sudowned Really? In that case you maybe need to provide more information on what's special about your scenario, because the above sample code I just edited in works fine.

Comment: Not sure there's anything special about my scenario at all! Your solution appears to partially work in this case, but it moves the cursor back to the start of the line - but I'm also not seeing any "Foo" lines actually get written. I'm starting to grow alarmed - maybe this is some weird Mono problem that doesn't affect .NET in general? Would you mind sharing the entire script, including the class declarations and so-forth?

Comment: Actually, hold that thought. I might have figured out how to make your solution work properly. Apologies, will post source if I crack the problem. ;]

Comment: Yeah, that worked out - I apologize for not accepting sooner, it completely slipped my mind. I believe I ended up using Console.Write for repeating the input text, though after adding arrowkey-assisted editing and up/down previous message navigation the code's not succinct enough to excerpt meaningfully.

Comment: this throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on Windows as soon as fooCursorTop equals 300.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler 300 is the default buffer height of a Windows command prompt. You could increase that, or add some others smarts to deal with it. Look at the `Console.BufferHeight` property, maybe `Console.MoveBufferArea(..)` method or even `Console.SetBufferSize(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Console.Out.Flush() after Console.WriteLine()? It should emit the data from buffer to output stream.

Comment: Tried it, no luck. It does not appear to have any result whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NullLib.ConsoleEx` to solve this problem.

> Install it through nuget package manager

It re-implements the console input logic based on ReadKey and does not destroy the content already entered by the user when using WriteLine. Replace 'Console.WriteLine' and 'Console.ReadLine' in your program with 'ConsoleSc.WriteLine' and 'ConsoleSc.ReadLine' respectively.